# Select polygons that contain attribute listed in a separate table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, attribute-joins, select-by-attribute

I am using ArcGIS Pro and am trying to select a number of polygons based on a list of postcodes from a standalone table.

I am using the Code-Point Polygon Dataset for the entirety of England, and I am trying to divide this into the 9 regions of England (e.g. East of England, North West, North East etc.) by using the postcodes.io dataset (https://postcodes.io/docs). I have a table listing the postcodes that are in each region, but I can't figure a way to select the polygons from the Code-Point dataset based on whether the postcode is contained within a given region.

Essentially, I have a standalone table listing the postcodes that fall within the East of England, and I want to select the polygons that have a postcode attribute that is matched within that table.

Answer (score 0):

Try to join the table to your feature class, using either Add Join (temporary), or Join Field (permanent), and then Select by Attribute on the region field.

Comment: Thank you - I hadn't considered this! Now having trouble with ArcGIS Pro endless batch joining fields where null values exist...